# REST to get list item by Id

Tags: 2013, rest, splistitem

I am always comfortable using `JSOM`, and I have used less of `REST` calls to access lists and its Items.

But now I have a requirement to use only `REST` to get item by its ID.

Is there any code snippet to get list item by its ID. I get ID in query string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this ([Excerpt from here](http://www.plusconsulting.com/blog/2013/05/crud-on-list-items-using-rest-services-jquery/)):

```
function getListItem(url, listname, id, complete, failure) {
    // Getting our list items
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + id + ")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            complete(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Official documentation from MS provides all possible examples.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

This will return an individual item.

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items(item id)
method: GET
headers:

Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" or "application/atom+xml"
```